# maps showing multiple markers when changing directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i'm showing directions on google maps and everything works fine. The problem is when i update one of the markers (departure or arrival) a new marker gets added to the map instead of removing the previous one. I've tried to set directionsDisplay as a global variable but couldn't get rid of the problem. Is there a way to clear the map before showing a new route?

here's how it looks like:

i have also tried this as suggested on the api:

```
directionDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
directionDisplay.suppressMarkers = true;
directionDisplay.setMap(null);![enter image description here][1]
```

thanks for the help

my code is

```
    var map = drawMap(map, mapOptions);
    var departure;
    var arrival;
    var marker = createMarker();

    function mainMap(mapOptions) {
    departure1 = '#autocomplete_departure';
    arrival1 = '#autocomplete_arrival';

    var placeDeparture = getAddress(departure1);
    var placeArrival = getAddress(arrival1);


      google.maps.event.addListener(placeDeparture, 'place_changed', function(){
        placeMarker(placeDeparture, departure1);
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(placeArrival, 'place_changed', function(){
        placeMarker(placeArrival, arrival1);
      });
  };

function setMarkerPosition(marker, place){
  marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
  marker.setMap(map);
}

function drawMap(){
  return new google.maps.Map(map, mapOptions);
}

function createMarker(){
  var markerOptions = {
    map: map
  }
  return new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
}


function placeMarker(place, stop){
  var place = place.getPlace();
  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);   
  } else {
    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(17);
  }

  marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
  marker.setMap(map);

    if (stop == '#autocomplete_departure') {
      departure = stop;
    } else if (stop == '#autocomplete_arrival') {
      arrival = stop;
    }

    if (arrival !== undefined && departure !== undefined) {
      updateRouteOnMap(arrival, departure);
    }

  function updateRouteOnMap(departure, arrival){
    var from = $(departure).val();
    var to = $(arrival).val();

    var request = {
      origin: from,
      destination: to,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    var directionsDisplay;
    if (directionsDisplay != undefined) directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        $("#directions-panel").html()
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));
      }
      else{
        alert("there has been an error. Please try again!")
      } 
    });
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You need to hide/remove your "marker" variable from the map before overwriting it with a new one.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, it is my first post so will try to pay more attention next time. I put the whole code for the map as i tried to remove the market in different parts before asking but didn't get any result, so i'm a bit confused on how to proceed. thanks for the help

Comment: i've cleaned the code to the relevant bits. I've tried to use a function to remove the markers before DirectionsRenderer() is called but didn't do any result. any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after several attempt i managed to find a solution.

i set directionsDisplay and directionsService as global variables and add this bit of code before drawing the map:

```
directionsDisplay.setDirections({routes: []});
```

this will reset the map every time a new direction is entered.